# Filtering Value or Blank in Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, match

I would like to filter a specific value as well as blank values.

**Example:** Filter if the value is "VALUE" or ""

I tried this:

```
=filter({Summation!E2:K},match(Summation!D2:D,{$B$1,""},false))
```

And also tried this:

```
=filter({Summation!E2:K},or(match(Summation!D2:D,{$B$1},false),isblank(Summation!D2:D)))
```

But non of these work. How do I match for blank values. I want all blank values as well as those with the value B1.

Comment: Use `(cond1+cond2)` instead of `OR(cond1,cond2)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `=QUERY(B1:K,"Select * where B='' and B='VALUE'",0)`

That selects all data in the range B1:K where column B is blank (`B=''`) AND where B is equal to VALUE (`B='VALUE'`).

Replace `B` with whatever column contains the value you're trying to find.